# "Unspecified Error" when renaming folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10, rename

Since the start of the week I can't rename folders anymore. I can create and delete files and folders, and rename files, but renaming folders result in a "unspecified error". This happens regardless if the folder already existed or was recently created, and in both C: (my SSD) and E: (my HDD) drives.

The console command `ren` still works, but renaming through any Explorer interface (Explorer window, Desktop, Open File dialog,...) fails in the same way.

It's not any antivirus (the only one I'm using is Windows Defender) and the problem persists with all user programs and their associated services stopped. I'm fairly sure I don't have any viruses either.

This is genuine, clean Windows 10 install. I found other people with similar problems, but all of them were drive-specific, which this is not.

[image: unspecified error]

Comment: I have since reinstalled Windows twice and changed computers, so I'm afraid I can't reproduce the error again and won't be accepting any answer. Sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer reproducible and there is insufficient information to answer it.

Comment: Answered here....https://superuser.com/questions/1390293/error-0x80004005-unspecified-error-when-renaming-folders-in-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: A few days later and the problem is back. I'm un-accepting this answer, but it may hold some solution.**

I think I figured it out. This has fixed the error for me.

## Cause

A special folder (e.g. *Desktop*, *Images*, *Downloads*, *Videos*, etc) has an invalid path as location (because the drive has been renamed or is missing).

## Symptoms

- The *This PC* shortcuts in Explorer contains items that when clicked trigger an error (as expected).
- Changing the location of the bugged items results in a new item, and the bugged one remains (unexpected).
- Renaming folders in Explorer results in `0x80004005 Unspecified Error` (very unexpected).

## Fix

1. Open `regedit`, perform a search for the path of the bugged item, and manually replace the value.
2. Restart the computer or kill and restart `explorer.exe`.

Comment: I can't find a path with this directory location.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Windows 10, I am getting this and other disk errors all the time.  Ghost folders, duplicate folders (with the same name but different contents), Files and Folders I can not rename or delete.

**My solution** is I have a global folder called corrupted and I am able to MOVE all of these to the corrupted folder.  Incidentally chkdisk does nothing.  I am waiting for some tool to appear in the future to sort it out.

I also notice that some of these are not actually files/folders or shortcuts but unix style links.

Comment: This happens to all folders, old and new, in all drives. Still waiting for an answer :/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix that works for me.

**CHKDSK**

I found that CHKDSK from from Drive Management does not work too well.  It is best to go to command line and type in

```
chkdsk C: /f
```

It must have /f for fix.  This worked on one of my pcs.

**DOS 8.3**

After a lot of trial and error, this worked on the rest of my pcs.

1. Open command prompt on the parent folder
2. Type in `dir /x`
3. This will list 8.3 file names
4. Select one filename at a time and delete it (most of mine went at this step)

   del CORRUP~1
5. If this does not work then reset attribs on both the files and possible links

   attrib -r -h -s *.*

   attrib -r -h -s *.* /l
6. Try deleting again (most of the remainder went at this stage)
7. Go back to explorer and delete them (all of mine disappeared at this stage).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem happens with any folder (so no corrupted folders to remove) and `chkdsk` didn't fix it.