# "Error 0x80004005: Unspecified error" when renaming folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, rename

I've managed to mess up windows 10, so it produces quite many odd errors.

One of them - even if you try to create new folder and / or rename existing one - explorer produces an error "Error 0x80004005: Unspecified error"

[image: Folder rename error]

Problem started to manifest after I have used `SHChangeNotify` function call (either powershell or C#) by changing `RoamingAppData` / guid `3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D`.

Reasking same question as in ["Unspecified Error" when renaming folders in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/966603/unspecified-error-when-renaming-folders-in-windows-10), because I managed to find an answer to this problem.

Comment: Are you connected to an Active Directory domain? If that is the case you should edit your question to indicate that is indeed the case.

Comment: Posted my reply to this question. See below. Hope that will help someone. You were too quick to ask questions. :)

Comment: Your solution was exactly the cause I thought your issue was caused by, my research linked it to an issue with AD though, hence my request for information

Answer (score 3):

In my case I've managed to change personal folder in following registry path:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

and I had `AppData` value as in invalid - should be set to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming`.

Please notice that you might have other personal folders as invalid ones, one approach how to detect this one - is to use process monitor with registry capturing enabled.

1. Start process monitor (Download it if you don't have one). Enable "Show Registry Activity".
2. You will get a lot of registry entries. Like anti-virus, windows processes, etc... accessing registry. Right click in "Process name" on each entry appearing and select "Exclude ". All processes except "Explorer". Until almost no new registry entries appears. Press "Clear" periodically to start from clean table.
3. Switch to explorer, rename folder. Error appers.
4. Quickly switch back to Process monitor and disable capture (but don't clear logs)
5. Search for access to registry path `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\Escalation`, then look back a little bit - you will find non-working personal folder. You can use even right click and "Jump to" to locate where in registry that one is.

Compare to working PC of what those registry entries should be.

[image: Process monitor]